# Nilpotent ideals of algebra over a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have 2 questions about the nilpotent ideals of an algebra $A$ over a field $K$.

- Each non-nilpotent left ideal of $A$ contains a nonzero idempotent element of $A$.
- The sum of all left nilpotent ideals of $A$ is still nilpotent.

For the first question, I tried to prove by contradiction but I have no idea how to show that the ideal is nilpotent.

For the second question, I can prove it when the number of left nilpotent ideals is finite, but I can't deal with the case that there are infinitely many left nilpotent ideals or show that's impossible.

Comment: Are you assuming the algebra is finite dimensional?  (It’s common, figured I’d ask). I’m also fairly sure I see the answer in that case.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm afraid not because such problems are used to give the definition of Jacobson radical of $A$. But I will be grateful if you can give some hints on the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: does “such problems” refer to this one or does it refer to others in your book which assume finite dimensionality? For that matter, are you using a text we can refer to?

Comment: @rschwieb These problems above are taken from the handout of my algebra lecture, and it uses several lemmas including the two above to introduce the Jacobson radical of an algebra. Sadly I have no idea where my handout is referred from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Counterexamples in the infinite dimensional case

The first proposition is not even true for commutative algebras in general: in $F[x,y]/(xy, x^2)$, the ideal generated by $y$ is not nilpotent (you can check it looks just like polynomials in $y$ over $F$) and contains no nonzero idempotents.

And, as you noted, the sum of finitely many nilpotent left ideals is nilpotent, but it is not so clear for infinite sums. For the second proposition, consider $R=F[x_1, x_2,\ldots]/(\{x_i^i\mid i\geq 2\})$. The sum $\sum _{i=2}^\infty (x_i)$ isn't nilpotent.

This leads me to suspect that the intended context was finite dimensional algebras. If $A$ is left Artinian both can be done, and finite dimensionality would do that simply.

The two things mentioned are properties of left Artinian rings: the former because of idempotent lifting (I think) and the latter because a sum of left ideals is equal to a finite sum of left ideals.

### For complete proofs

It seems like an elementary proof that a non-nilpotent left ideal contains a nonzero idempotent is fiddly and I am reluctant to do a transcription. The one I have in mind is here

> Curtis, Charles W., and Irving Reiner. Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras. Vol. 356. American Mathematical Soc., 1966.

on page 160, Theorem 24.2.  Presently I can view the pages [in google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Representation_Theory_of_Finite_Groups_a/RKwjeZKMr8oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Curtis+and+Reiner:+Representation+Theory+of+Finite+Groups+and+Associative+Algebras&printsec=frontcover)

Then a few pages later, theorem 24.4 is that the sum of nilpotent left ideals is an ideal.

In both cases, it is postulated that the ring "has minimum condition" which means that it is Artinian.

Comment: Could you please give some more details about the finite-dimensional case? The lecture I attended didn't cover Artinian rings.

Comment: @MegaOwIer I'm trying to think of an elementary way... but I must be missing the trick.

Comment: @MegaOwIer Added some details. It seems like an elementary proof is not very concise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following your hints, I completed the proof and posted a new answer. Please help to check its correctness if you're convenient.

Answer (score 0):

With the claim that $\dim A$ should be **finite** and the hints from @rschwieb, I tried to work out a way to complete the proof.

### For the first proposition

Given a left ideal $I$ of $A$, obviously $I$ is closed under addition. For any $k \in K$ and $x \in I$ we also have
$$
kx = 1 \cdot (kx) = (k1) \cdot x \in I
$$
Hence $I$ becomes a $K$-linear subspace of $A$.

Note that $\dim I \leq \dim A < +\infty$, we can take $x_1, \cdots, x_k$ as basis of $I$ and then
$$
I = Ax_1 \oplus Ax_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus Ax_k
$$
For non-nilpotent left ideal $I$, there must be some $i$ such that $Ax_i$ is also non-nilpotent. So we just need to consider the left ideal given by $J = Ax_1$.

Obviously $\dim J = 1$. The fact that $J$ is non-nilpotent leads to $Jx_1 = J$, which is to say $Ax_1^2 = Ax_1$, so we can find some $a \in A$ such that
$$
ax_1^2 = x_1
$$
Then one can check that $ax_1$ is idempotent.

### For the second proposition

It seems can also be proved by observing left ideals as subspaces to show that a sum of left ideals is equal to a finite sum of left ideals.

Comment: The representation of I as a *direct* sum of k copies of $A$ need not exist. Of course the plain sum $\sum Ax_i$ would be just fine. Then, there is no reason to expect any of these would be $1$-dimensional over $K$. Yes, they are cyclic $A$ modules, but they could have a higher $K$ dimension.  So $Jx_1$ cannot be shown to be minimal w.r.t. being nonnilpotent this way. Even if it is, it is not clear that $ax_1$ is idempotent (without commutativity.)

Comment: You might prove me wrong, but I have a feeling that the fact we're dealing with a finite dimensional algebra over a field will not really radically simplify what had to be done in the proofs in the Curtis and Reiner book.

Comment: I think it can be proved that $ax_1$ is idempotent if $J$ is 1-dimensional. This is because $(ax_1)^2 \cdot x_1 = ax_1 \cdot x_1$ and $Jx_1 = J$ tells that right multiplication by $x_1$ will not make a non zero element become 0.

Comment: And this proof seems can be fixed. Consider $Ax_1 \supset Ax_1^2 \supset \cdots$, if we can show $Ax_1^n$ will never be $0$, then there must be some $x = x_1^n$ such that $Ax^2 = Ax$.

Comment: If $Ax$ is $1$ dimensional then yes it is trivial because $Ax=Kx$ and everything commutes.  But $Ax$ will not always be $1$ dimensional.

Comment: The other comment may be relevant for repairing the other part. I agree that it is possible to show $Ax^2=Ax$ for some nonzero $x$.  What then?  I think the linked proof spends a lot of time extracting that information.

Comment: Can we do the following part by observing the linear function $f : a \mapsto ax$ from $J = Ax$ to itself, and get $\operatorname{Ker}(f) = 0$ from $Jx = J$?

Comment: no, because in an Artinian ring $\ker f=0$ implies $x$ is a unit.